# How to respond to a promise resolved inside a Vue event handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, async-await

Given the following component

```html
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-dialog
      v-model="dialog"
      width="500"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          color="red lighten-2"
          dark
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        >
          Click Me
        </v-btn>
      </template>

      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="headline grey lighten-2">
          Privacy Policy
        </v-card-title>

        <v-card-text>
          Some text
        </v-card-text>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn
            color="primary"
            text
            @click="handleAsyncAction"
          >
            I accept
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from "vue-class-component";

@Component()
export class MyDialog extends Vue {
 dialog: booolean = false;
 
  async handleAsyncAction() {
  const value = await this.$emit('click'); // you can't really do that
  if(value === 'x') {
    dialog = false; //<--- then close
  } else {
   alert('error!')
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

Used by some parent like this:

```html
<template>
 <div>
  <MyDialog @click="makeSomeAjaxRequest($event)"
 </div>
</template>

<script type="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from "vue-class-component";
import MyDialog from "./MyDialog"

@Component({
  components: { MyDialog }
})
export default class ParentComponent extends Vue {
  async makeSomeAjaxRequest() {
    const data = await fetch('http://example.com');
    return data.toString();
  }

}
</script>
```

Using React you'll be just able to pass some function from the parent and wrap the whole thing up, but from my understanding, this is not the Vue way of doing things.

How should I approach making the child component 'await' for the call to be back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue stores all of the relevant event listeners inside the component under [this.$listeners](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components)

By leveraging that, you'll be able to invoke the function without emitting an actual event:

```
// MyDialog
async handleAsyncAction() {
  //@ts-ignore since Vue 2s' TS definitions condone such behavior
  const value = await this.$listeners.click();
  if(value === 'x') {
    dialog = false; //<--- then close
  } else {
   alert('error!')
  }
 }
}
```

You can see a complete example in an article named [Reacting to Promises from event listeners in Vue.js](https://medium.com/@dobromir_hristov/reacting-to-promises-from-event-listeners-in-vue-js-8959b6d03f52)